# Regex: plus sign not doing what I expect

Tags: regex

I have a file with many lines including a string like this: blah blah **num=12345;** blah blah

I would like to find lines where the number after the equals sign is greater than 1, with no upper limit. (I do not expect a number to ever start with zero.)

I started with this expression that will match any number starting with any digit that's not a 1, and it works fine and I understand it.

```
grep 'num=[2-9][0-9]*;'
```

This next expression *should*, I thought, return any number starting with a 1 that has two or more digits, but I instead get nothing back:

```
grep 'num=1[0-9]+;'
```

I though the above meant: must match **num=1**, then must match something between 0-9 one or more times, then must match **;**. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

With grep you must escape the + quantifier

```
grep 'num=1[0-9]\+;'
```

For your problem you can use this (for all numbers >1, if i understand well):

```
grep 'num=\([2-9]\|1[0-9]\)[0-9]*;'
```

Comment: Ha! that worked, thanks. After a bit more reading what I ended up with is grep -E 'num=1[0-9]+;|num=[2-9][0-9]*;' myfile. Curious if that is indeed the best way?

Comment: Actually, I think your edit is too broad...I'd get things like 'num=1;' which I don't want.

Comment: @user2063292: ok now i have it.

Comment: @user2063292: your solution, for a **very** large dataset, could cause a little bit more of backtracking (I don't know how optimized grep's regex engine would be). But it is approximately the same thing.

Comment: Actually it should be this: grep -E -c 'size=([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+);'. Casimir, you solution excluded numbers of 2 or more digts that don't start with one.